# Typescript: How to access and update class variable from public function

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to access value of a class variable in function setRating() but the console print is "undefined".

```
export class UserFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {    

  rating: number;    

  constructor() {
    this.rating = 3;
  }    

  ngOnInit() {
    //initial setup
    console.log("Rating " + this.rating);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
      stars.forEach(function(star) {
        star.addEventListener('click', setRating);
      });

      let temps = parseInt(document.querySelector('.stars').getAttribute('data-rating'));
      console.log("Rating 2: " + this.rating);
      let target = stars[temps - 1];
      target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));   

    });    

  }


  function setRating(ev) {
    //Printing 'undefined' in console.log
    console.log('At top: ' + this.rating);
    let span = ev.currentTarget;
    let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
    let match = false;
    let num = 0;
    stars.forEach(function(star, index) {
      if (match) {
        star.classList.remove('rated');
      } else {
        star.classList.add('rated');
      }
      //are we currently looking at the span that was clicked
      if (star === span) {
        match = true;
        num = index + 1;
      }

    });

    this.rating = num;

    console.log("value after update: " + this.rating)
    document.querySelector('.stars').setAttribute('data-rating', num.toString());    

  }

}
```

the "value after update: " console log prints "undefined" unless this.rating is assigned to num. Can someone please help me with how to access the value of rating variable in setRating() function and how to update its value?

Answer (score 0):

It's a context binding issue, you have to bind the `setRating` function to the class `this` otherwise it is going to use its own `this` which is different than the classes `this` no having access to `this.rating`. You can achieve this by using `setRating.bind(this)`.

You can start by changing the `DOMContentLoaded` to an arrow function so that you inherit the context's `this` like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   // this.rating is visible here now
   ...
})
```

Then you can do the same to the `forEach` handler:

```
stars.forEach((star) => {
   // this.rating is visible here now too
    ...
});
```

Finally, you can bind the `this` of your external function to the classes `this`:

```
star.addEventListener('click', setRating.bind(this));
```

Your final code would be something like bellow:

```js
export class UserFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
  rating: number;

  constructor() {
    this.rating = 3;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //initial setup
    console.log("Rating " + this.rating);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
      stars.forEach((star) => {
        star.addEventListener('click', setRating.bind(this));
      });

      let temps = parseInt(document.querySelector('.stars').getAttribute('data-rating'));
      console.log("Rating 2: " + this.rating);

      let target = stars[temps - 1];
      target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    });
  }


  function setRating(ev) {
    //Printing 'undefined' in console.log
    console.log('At top: ' + this.rating);
    let span = ev.currentTarget;
    let stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
    let match = false;
    let num = 0;
    stars.forEach(function(star, index) {
      if (match) {
        star.classList.remove('rated');
      } else {
        star.classList.add('rated');
      }
      //are we currently looking at the span that was clicked
      if (star === span) {
        match = true;
        num = index + 1;
      }

    });

    this.rating = num;

    console.log("value after update: " + this.rating)
    document.querySelector('.stars').setAttribute('data-rating', num.toString());
  }
}
```

> **Further observation:** You are declaring a `function` inside a class, that is totally unnecessary, you can declare it as a member
>
> ```
> export class UserFeedbackComponent implements OnInit { 
>     ...
>     setRating(ev) {
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then you don't even ave to bind it to call it like so:
>
> ```
> star.addEventListener('click', ev => this.setRating(ev));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to define the function using the `function` keyword in the class. Declare it as a class member and you should be able to access it normally. This is the best practice in Typescript class declaration.

EX:

```
export class UserFeedbackComponent implements OnInit {    

  rating: number;    

  constructor() {
    this.rating = 3;
  }    

  ngOnInit() {
    //initial setup
    console.log("Rating " + this.rating);
    ......................more code............
  }


  setRating(ev) {
    //Printing 'undefined' in console.log
    console.log(this.rating); //should work fine
    // do other stuff with class members
  }

}
```